# How to print multiple items in a list as a string?

Tags: python, string, list, printing

I have a list called combined with many items. I would like to print the first three items as a string, each all on a new line. If I type:

```
print str(combined[0])
```

;it will print the first item out as as string, without being inside [''].

However if I try to do the same with the first three by using:

```
print str(combined[0:3])
```

;it prints the first three items, but still in a list.

How can I get these three items of the list to print out as strings with each on a new line?

Comment: print "\n".join(combined[:3])

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print "\n".join(combined[0:3])
```

From the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> `str.join(iterable)`
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable iterable. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

If your list `combined` contains non-strings, you might first want to convert them to strings (e.g. with `map(str, ...)`:

```
print "\n".join(map(str, combined[0:3]))
```

Comment: One minor point - python allows you to say `combined[:3]` if you mean to start from the head of the list. This is a little more precise, and is generally preferred over `combined[0:3]` (similarly you would say `some_list[-3:]` to indicate that you want the final three elements of the list)

Comment: I prefer the shorter syntax too, @JonKiparsky, but tried to stick to the original expression from the question as much possible, just to be clearer.